# Moving access 2003 reports to crystal reports

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports

I just moved a desktop application developed on ms access 2003 to a c# version using crystal reports for reporting. Is there a way for me to move the existing numerous reports from ms access 2003 to crystal reports? talking in terms of the reports design view since they will all remain the same instead of recreating them in crystal reports all over again.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible to do. You will have to rewrite each report from scratch.

If there is no particular reason why you must use Crystal Reports take a look at SSRS instead.  You can [import Access Reports to SSRS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834306).